# Bit Order of Java BitSet

Tags: java, byte, endianness, bitset

I have the following code:

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[1];
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt("127");
byteArr[0] = b;
BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(byteArr);
```

After setting a breakpoint following the last line, I get an unexpected debugger output:

[image]

In binary terms, it appears 'bs' has the value '11111110' whereas I'd expect it to have the value '01111111' (127). It doesn't seem to be explainable with truncation, as only the last 8 bits are relevant (and the MSB of 127 is unset).

This is an issue because I'd like to use it as a bitmask for other bitstrings. What is causing this behavior? Is there a workaround to preserve the expected bit ordering?

Comment: What?  That looks just fine.  I'm not sure how you interpret that as "11111110".

Comment: I interpreted {0, 1, 2...} as the indices of set bits within the BitSet. Since the first seven bits are set, it appears that the BitSet has a value of '11111110' (decimal 254).

Comment: @MichaelHang Then how do you know the BitSet represents 8 bits?

Comment: The byte[] byteArr is populated with a single byte. I'm assuming that the BitSet static constructor does not remove trailing unset bits.

Also, running the code with Integer.parseInt("254") returns {1, 2, .., 7}

Comment: Index `0` is the right-most bit. So, `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}` means every bit is set except the left-most bit, i.e. `01111111`.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity: why `(byte) Integer.parseInt("127")' and not `(byte) 127`?

Comment: @devjuth: Is there a purpose to why the bits are backwards?
korolar: I'm creating a netmask from an ip address in string form.

Answer (score 1):

*BitSet* allocates words (represented as long array) and they are created depending on the number of bits needed.

As you want to represent only one byte , so it can be represented as one word (with in 64 bits / long). In 64 bits it is little-endian representation,  bits are ordered from least significant to most significant.

You can check yourself using get(int bitIndex), which does "and" operation on the word to return bit set at that position